# Very strange - Looks like Facebook Graph does not like alcohol or is permission required?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

When I go to http://graph.facebook.com/SomePageName ideally it should show info about the page. I was looking for page id of specific pages and found a very strange thing. On checking the following links I get error whereas the pages are in existence:

```
graph.facebook.com/BacardiIndia
graph.facebook.com/mcdsignature
graph.facebook.com/smirnoffindian
graph.facebook.com/fostersindia
```

Error below

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Is there any kind of permission required or Facebook does not like indian alcohol :)

Got two more such IDs

```
https://www.facebook.com/bmwindia
https://www.facebook.com/FranklinTempletonIndia
```

How can I get their Page Ids?

EDIT: Thanks. It is indeed a question of similar nature. When I tried to find it I could not. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: They are most likely age gated. Which means that you need to use a user access token from a user that is old enough

Comment: I found two more IDs. BMW is a car maker and Franklin is a financial institution

Comment: They can also have set country restrictions on their pages and then there is the same rule. You need to use a user access token that is in that country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with age or country restrictions. What is the age and location of the person who's token you are using?

Comment: Thanks... I am not using a token. I saw numerous pages without any error. I found two more such urls edited in the question

Comment: Try using a token from someone 21+ in the graph explorer.